# ASp:NET How to perform Date Difference validation on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-validators

I need to validate the input so the difference between Date1 and Date2 no more then 30 days.

I'm trying to use custom validation in asp.net, but not sure if in my case it would be the correct choice.

I have the following `html`:

```
.
.
.
 <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFileDate" runat="server">File Date: from</asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker1"></asp:TextBox>    
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDateFrom" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateFrom" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Date From is Required" ValidationGroup="vgForm" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left:40px; text-align:right;">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDateTo" runat="server" >to:</asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td width="165">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTo" runat="server" colspan="2" CssClass="datepicker2"></asp:TextBox>   
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDateTo" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateTo" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Date To is Required" ValidationGroup="vgForm" >*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cstDateValidation" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Date difference should not be more then 30 days" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDateDiff"></asp:CustomValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right;" colspan="4">
            <asp:Button id="btnSearch" Text="Search" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" runat="server"  
            CausesValidation="true" CommandName="Search" OnCommand="btnSearch_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateFields()" />
        </td>
</tr>
.
.
.

<div id="errorDisplay">
     <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vSum" runat="server" ShowSummary="true" ValidationGroup="vgForm"></asp:ValidationSummary>   
</div>
```

This is my `javascript`:

```
function ValidateFields() {

    var isValid = false;

    isValid = Page_ClientValidate('vgForm');
        if (!isValid) {
            $('#errorDisplay').dialog({
                title: "Validation Error",
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                width: 250,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

function ValidateDateDiff(sender, args) {
        var dateFrom = $('#cphBody_Cnt_txtDateFrom').val();
        var dateTo = $('#cphBody_Cnt_txtDateTo').val();

        var diff = dateFrom - dateTo;
        if (diff > 30) {
           args.IsValid = false;
        }        
}
```

What is the best way to do something like that?

Comment: See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you, this was a good post. It helped a lot